# How is cash game winner reward calculated?

Tags: cash-game

I was watching other people playing online cash games, and just can't understand how the reward was calculated. See the picture below:

[image: screenshot of logs]

Why the winner only took a portion of the pot?

Although the screenshot does not show the total pot, we can guess the pot from adding up all the bets from the log.

The third one has clearly a pot of total $3.65, but the winner only took $2.50. Is that because of the rake took $1.15? 1.15/3.65 = 31.5% of rake does not sound right.

The other two clearly is not because rake.

Why the winner only took a small portion of the pot and where did the rest of the pot go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only called bets are accounted in earned pot (and in rake calculations). Raising counts as calling a bet, and partially called bets (all-ins for ex.) are counted as being of the size of the called portion.

In a simple situation, if a player bets 5 into a 10 pot and his bet isn't called, the pot is counted as being 10.

When raising, if the initial pot is 10, A bets 5, B raises to 15, and A folds, the pot is 10 + 5 bet + 5 called = 20.

Considering all-ins if the pot is 10, A bets 10 and is all-in, B calls for his stack of 5, the pot is still 10 + 5 bet + 5 called = 20.

Some rooms do mention "Uncalled xx$ returned to someplayer" in the log to help understanding where does the remaining of the pot went.